# Classification of color based on HSV values

Tags: algorithm, neural-network

I am making an algorithm to output what color (eg. red, orange, violet) given HSV values. I was thinking of using a neural network for this task, because I feel that a neural network could learn to account for lighting differences between actual and expected colors. Is a neural net overkill the best way to approach this, or should I use something different, possibly simpler?

Comment: As is this has nothing to do with Java, so I'd remove that tag and add neural-network since you are asking specifically about them. This is an interesting concept, but I think the answer depends on how much detail (how many colors) you want to output. Also, how will it be trained?

Comment: @whrrgarbl it would be trained by giving being given a series of HSV values and the correct color between red, orange, yellow, green, blue, and violet for each corresponding HSV datum, then trained using gradient descent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple classification task. You have a three-dimensional space (HSV) and your defined colors (red, orange, violet, ...) are vectors in that space. Now for any given HSV value you can find the closest defined color, just by finding the minimum euclidean distance.